# How to check an entire Excel worksheet for specific text in formulas?

Tags: excel-formula, contains, sumifs

I am looking for a formula that will check an entire worksheet if any of the formulas in that worksheet contain "SUMIF". If there are any, the formula should return "Yes", otherwise "No".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do the following:

1. Select a range and name it. This is so you can use it in a formula later
2. Use the `COUNTIF` formula with the name range.

   `=COUNTIF(YourRange, "=SUMIF")`
3. Surround that with the `IF` formula to transform the 1 or 0 to "Yes" or "No"

   `=IF(COUNTIF(YourRange, "=SUMIF")=1, "Yes", "No")`

Comment: Countif will not look at the formula but the return of the formula and as such will not find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Zum(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set r2 = rng

    On Error GoTo out
        Set r3 = r2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In r3
        t = r.Formula
        If InStr(t, "SUMIF") > 0 Then
            Zum = "Yes"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
out:
    Zum = "No"
End Function
```

It is based on `Range`, but you can set the range to all the cells on any particular worksheet.  For example to test `Sheet2`, put this is any cell in `Sheet1`:

```
=ZUM(Sheet2!1:1048576)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a formula route one must limit the search:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("=SUMIF",FORMULATEXT(Sheet2!A1:Z100))))),"Yes","No")
```

Trying to do a whole sheet will cause an error, due to lack of memory.